# Progress circle not running till it loads RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

I am trying to move from one activity A to another activity B.In activity B there is a recycler view,In that recycler view I am loading data in background thread(Using AsyncTask) from SQLite database.When I switch to activity B I have given a Progress Bar to show the loading of data.But that progress bar doesn't spin till it fully loads the data.I want it to spin to show loading is happening.

[This some what looks like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSjl5.jpg)

[When loading happens then it starts to spin,and looks like this.Running behind the recycler view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHgQO.jpg)

```
package com.freakydevs.kolkatalocal;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class TrainTable extends AppCompatActivity {
String from, to;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
Toolbar toolbar;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.train_table);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {
    public int FromStationId, ToStationId;
    String sday, sday1, sday2, sday3;
    int check = 5;
    private List<Train> trainList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TrainTableAdapter trainTableAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        sday = intent.getStringExtra("day");

        from = intent.getStringExtra("From");
        to = intent.getStringExtra("To");
        FromStationId = intent.getIntExtra("trainId", 0);
        ToStationId = intent.getIntExtra("trainId1", 0);
        check = intent.getIntExtra("samay", 0);


    }


    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {

       //Some codes are here to make a cursor and send it to postExecute
        c3 = SQ.rawQuery(s, null);
        return c3;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Cursor cursor) {



        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            ShowNoTrain();


        } else {



            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.tiimetable_list);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    trainTableAdapter = new TrainTableAdapter(TrainTable.this, cursor, from, to);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(TrainTable.this);
                            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(trainTableAdapter);
                            trainTableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();


        }

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        this.finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

public void ShowNoTrain() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TrainTable.this);

    // set title
    //alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Invalid Date");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("No Train Available for this Route!")
            .setCancelable(false);

    //final AlertDialog my = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // create alert dialog


    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}


}
```

Comment: care to post some code? the layout of the view? the initialisation of the activity?

Comment: There are a large block of codes its not efficient to post all the codes.

Comment: Then we can only guess... Maybe you are making the progress bar spin after you load the data from SQLite?

Comment: Ok I am adding the code...Thanks a lot..I am struggling with this problem for more than 10 days.

Comment: use http://pastebin.com/ or something if you feel like theres a bit too much code.

Comment: Thank You.I have pasted the codes.